# JS Triggers fire correctly only on every other pageload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm running JQ 1.10.2 and JQM 1.4.0 The code has been trimmed for explanation.

`index.php`: Contains a number of menu items and the following JS. When a menu item is clicked, the JS is executed on the destination page because of `pagebeforeshow`. The destination page contains links back to `index.php`.

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow',function() {
    var baseHref = document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0].href;
    var filename = baseHref.split('/').pop();
    switch (filename) {
        case 'page1.php':
            $(this).on('tap','.log-item',function(){
                $(this).children('.log-item-more').toggle();
            });
            break;
        case 'page2.php':
            //other js
            break;
        case 'page3.php':
            //other js
            break;
    }
});
```

In short, that JS finds the destination's filename and uses a switch statement to determine which page-specific JS to load.

The unexplainable thing is that when I load up `index.php` and click the `page1.php` link, `page1.php` loads as expected and it's JS from the switch statement works as expected as well. Next, I click the link to go back to `index.php`, then click the link to goto `page1.php`, the page loads as expected but the JS doesn't fire this time.

If I repeat the back and forth, the JS works 1 time, then doesn't the next and continues in this predictable 'on/off' cycle. I've never seen this behavior before and I'm at a loss.

**UPDATE:**

After further looking into this. I realize that the code within the switch statement is initialized each time the page is created. That means that the `.on('tap')` event listener is initialized once on the 1st page load, 2x on the 2nd page load, 3x on the 3rd page load, etc. I'm using a `toggle`, which is `hide` or `show`, and that's why it appeared that the code was not working when in fact is was!

Now, my question is *which event should I be listening for in place of `pagebeforeshow` to only be triggered the 1st time that particular page is loaded in the session?*

**UPDATE:**

Looking at the jQuery Mobile API Documentation, it looks like [pagecreate](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecreate/) is the event listener I'm looking for, but it behaves just like [pagebeforeshow](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagebeforeshow/) and [pageinit](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pageinit/).

I don't know why these events are acting this way... are they broken in this version of jQM?

Or am I linking these pages incorrectly? Perhaps `<a href='log.php' data-transition='flip'>Log Page</a>` is the wrong way to construct the anchor?

Comment: Can you verify that the baseHref is what you expect each time, or put a default in the switch and see what your filename is there. My guess is that your filename is no longer what you expect on the second go around.

Comment: That's a good thought, but I have an alert inside each case. So I can verify that the switch IS working properly.

Comment: Any chance you can share the rest of your code, jsfiddle perhaps?

Comment: I've posted my resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED:**

I was not following jQuery's [jQuery's Multiple Page Temple Structure](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/pages/#Multi-pagetemplatestructure) properly!

- I structured each page to be wrapped in a `<div data-role="page" id="pagename">` tag.
- I then included each page's JS just before closing that page's `data-role="page"` tag. **I did not wrap it in any event listener** (`$(document).on('pageinit',function(){ });`)!
- Lastly, on the dashboard.php (my webapp's home page, basically), I included `data-prefetch="true"` in each anchor tag.